# Getting 404 error while calling Web API 2 from MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing an ASP.Net MVC 5 application with Web API 2 and Entity Framework. I have created a **WEB API 2 Controller with actions, using Entity Framework** named **EmployeeAPIController** and consuming the API using ajax call as shown below.

```
function loadEmployees() {
    alert("In Load");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/EmployeeAPI",
        success: function (data) {
            self.Message("Success");
            self.Employees(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status);
        }
    });

};
```

But I'm always getting error 404. My RouteConfig file is configured as

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

What should be the reason for 404. I'm a beginner to MVC and Web API. Please help.

Comment: try taking out the first forward slash from the url you are trying to use in your AJAX call.

Comment: You've posted `RouteConfig` file, could you please look for `WebApiConfig` ?

Comment: Also post your api controller's action method, which you're trying to call.

Comment: `url: "/api/EmployeeAPI"` change to `url: "../api/EmployeeAPI",`

Comment: @MokshShah where can i find `WebApiConfig` ?
and my Action method is
'public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            return db.Employees;
        }
'

Comment: At same place where you've `RouteConfig` in `App_Start` folder

Comment: I have no such file generated. Can i add the file and where do the configuration  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has been solved. It was due to missing `WebApiConfig.cs` file in App_Start folder. I have manually added the file.

```
public class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

And configured the `Global.asax` like

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
```

It works for me. Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

You should have this in your webapi.config file-

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
}
```

And you should have the API Controller like below-

```
public class EmployeeAPIController : ApiController
    {
        //
        // GET: /API/EmployeeAPI/
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public EmployeeListModel Get()
        {
            ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the point of the XML formatter removal, in response to his question? It doesn't do anything useful (other than getting json from a plain chrome call).

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved. It was due to missing WebApiConfig.cs file in App_Start folder. I have manually added the file.

public class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

```
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And configured the Global.asax like

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

**!!IMPORTANT!!one more thing, delete xxxxxxAreaRegistration.cs"  from your area folder where is WEBAPI, otherwise it WOULD NOT work!**

works for me, MVC 5